# Why is my Symfony PdoSessionHandler not working?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to use the PdoSessionHandler in Symfony 5.4. When I'm following [the instructions on the Symfony site](https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/session/database.html#store-sessions-in-a-relational-database-mariadb-mysql-postgresql) nothing happens in the database each time a Symfony Session is called. Even when I'm removing the existing session files, removing the Symfony cache and restarting WAMPserver just to be sure, there are still new session files created.
Nothing appears in the Symfony logging pointing to this issue.
Of course I replaced DATABASE_URL in .env to the values that will work with my database.

My services.yaml looks like this:

```
# This file is the entry point to configure your own services.
# Files in the packages/ subdirectory configure your dependencies.

# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices.html#use-parameters-for-application-configuration
parameters:

services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.

    # makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    App\:
        resource: '../src/'
        exclude:
            - '../src/DependencyInjection/'
            - '../src/Entity/'
            - '../src/Kernel.php'

    # add more service definitions when explicit configuration is needed
    # please note that last definitions always *replace* previous ones

    Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\PdoSessionHandler:
        arguments:
            - '%env(DATABASE_URL)%'
```

And my framework.yaml looks like this:

```
# see https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html
framework:
    secret: '%env(APP_SECRET)%'
    #csrf_protection: true
    http_method_override: false

    # Enables session support. Note that the session will ONLY be started if you read or write from it.
    # Remove or comment this section to explicitly disable session support.
    session:
        handler_id: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\PdoSessionHandler
        cookie_secure: auto
        cookie_samesite: lax
        storage_factory_id: session.storage.factory.native


    #esi: true
    #fragments: true
    php_errors:
        log: true

when@test:
    framework:
        test: true
        session:
            storage_factory_id: session.storage.factory.mock_file
```

I created the table with the following query:

```
    CREATE TABLE `sessions` (
    `sess_id` VARBINARY(128) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    `sess_data` BLOB NOT NULL,
    `sess_lifetime` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `sess_time` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    INDEX `sessions_sess_lifetime_idx` (`sess_lifetime`)
) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin, ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

This part will be executed when there is someone logging on:

```
$session = new Session();
                
if(!isset($_SESSION)){
    $session->start();
}

$session->set('ownerid', $databasestuff);
```

Comment: Please post the controller code you are using to test the session write. As for debugging, verify `php bin/console debug:config framework` is aligned with what you believe is occurring in your configs. Additionally check the `APP_ENV` global variable is the appropriate setting.

Comment: I updated my post with one of the session writes. I checked with bin/console and at "session" it has the right handler_id, but the savepath is a local path. APP_ENV has the right value and when I'm entering a wrong password, the website will crash.

Comment: Should use `if (!$session->isStarted())` as opposed to `$_SESSION` but `$session->start();` does it for you automatically. The `save_path` being set to `%kernel.cache_dir%/session` is the [default config](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/5.4/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php#L662) and can be ignored. Only other things I can think to check is that `DATABASE_URL` is correct and the `src/Kernel.php` or `public/index.php` files are the default. As for *"crash"*, you mean displays an exception or the webserver service terminates?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The database URL is as following: `DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:root@localhost:3306/psaregister?serverVersion=5.7&charset=utf8mb4"`. It says the same when using `bin/console debug:container --env-vars`. I never touched Kernel.php or index.php. When I'm entering wrong credentials in the database url, I'll get a PdoExeption with the message Access denied. Any ideas left?

Comment: Initially misread password as login authenticator not `DATABASE_URL` MySQL password. The `session` settings in `phpinfo()` of your loaded environment may point to the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you are using Session, possibly from the Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session bundle.

I don't think this will work.
You might want to use the autowiring for your controller to wireup the SessionInterface.

For example:

```
namespace App\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
.
class DummyController extends AbstractController
{
    protected $Session;

    public function __construct(SessionInterface $Session)
    {
         $this->Session = $Session; //Setting the Session interface to the Session var
         if(!$this->Session->isStarted()) //Starting the session if not done yet
             $this->Session->start();
     }
}
```